# Fatal error: This socket is closed. ('grunt-contrib-imagemin')

Tags: sockets, gruntjs, long-running-processes

this is a gruntfile.json

```
     'use strict';
     module.exports = function(grunt) {


grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  imagemin: {
    options: {
      optimizationLevel: 3,
      flatten: true  ,
                   cache: false
    },
    build: {
      expand: true,
        cwd: 'public/images',
         src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],    
         dest: 'images/min'
    }
  }

});
     grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
 grunt.registerTask('default', ['imagemin']);
      };
```

and i got this error

Fatal error: This socket is closed.

and this is a full error details

```
Command-line options: --verbose
    Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK
    Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
Initializing config...OK
    Registering "grunt-contrib-imagemin" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\Mohamed\Desktop\egwebstorm\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\Mohamed\Desktop\egwebstorm\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\package.json...OK
Loading "imagemin.js" tasks...OK
+ imagemin
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ default
    No tasks specified, running default tasks.
Running tasks: default
    Running "default" task
    Running "imagemin" task
  Running "imagemin:build" (imagemin) task
Verifying property imagemin.build exists in config...OK
Files: public/images/facebook.png -> images/min/facebook.png
          ---- the list of other images -----
Options: interlaced, optimizationLevel=3, progressive, flatten, cache=false
Fatal error: This socket is closed.
```

and no image folder created or anything changed ,and i reviewed the code but i didn't know if there's something need to fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install imagemin:

```
npm uninstall grunt-contrib-imagemin
npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-imagemin
```